# Determining error between two surfaces given same discrete inputs?

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, data-fitting

I have, as an output of a machine learning algorithm, a surface in z, which has known increments along x and y. These points along x and y match exactly to a surface which I am comparing the output of my algorithm against in order to get a metric of fit, or error. I have been struggling to find an optimal way of calculating this, and can't find any good resources on different options that I have. I have tried simple pointwise subtraction of the surfaces, which I take the absolute value and summation of, and I have tried squared versions of this, as well as divided versions, but each of these encounters different problems. I was wondering if any of you knew of any good resources on different options and which of these work in different situations. Thanks!

Comment: Let me ask if I got the question right: You have two heightfields `z=f(x, y)`, where `x` and `y` are distributed in the same regular, uniform grid. And you want to compare the height fields. A natural choice for me would be squared differences. What problems did you encounter with these?

Comment: Well, squared differences actually works the best of them so far. My only issue is that i'm seeing it occasionally emphasizing certain features too much, such as if there are outliers in the comparison surface, and this causes the optimization to give nonsensical answers. I was hoping to find a way that would deemphasize things like the outliers, but all of the other methods I have tried (I have since tried MSE, RMSE, and R2) give out worse answers than squared differences.

Comment: Can you show two typical surfaces to be compared ? Are the errors identically distributed ?

Comment: How are you optimizing? It might be that the optimizer cannot deal with the discontinuous derivatives of the absolute differences, which should handle outliers pretty well. If that's the case, you can try a smoothed variant `error = sqrt(diff^2 + epsilon)`, where `epsilon` is a small number that defines the smoothness of the loss.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is outliers, compute all absolute height differences and discard the N/2 largest (or another fraction, depending on the usual proportion of outliers). Then take the average of the remaining ones (or the RMS). This is called a trimmed average.